# HTML string trailing off page with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to generate PDF documents from concatenated HMTL Strings.

I need to use this method rather than `getElementById()` as I am pulling the HTML dynamically using TypeScript.

I have been able to generate the PDF document from the HTML String, the issue is how the text displays on the PDF - it is trailing off the right of the screen (image below).

I have not been able to find an answer to this specific issue and have tried various methods to resolve this (explained below) with little success.

I am hoping there is a more simple approach, using a right margin, text wrapping or some other formatting capability within the jsPDF library, that someone could point me to?

**Text Trailing off to the right of PDF:**
[image]

Initially, I thought that adding the `margin` and `width` options below could correct this. But this was not the case.

**TypeScript Code (main function):**

```
generatePdf() {
    console.log('Generating PDF');
    // (orientation: portrait, units: pt, PDF page size: A4)
    const doc = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    const editor1Content = this.getEditorHtml(this.editorComponent1); // HTML string
    const editor2Content = this.getEditorHtml(this.editorComponent2); // HTML string
    const source = editor1Content + editor2Content; // combined HTML string
    console.log('source: ', source);
    // source is the HTML string or DOM elem ref. HTML String in this case.
    // width - max width of content on PDF
    // 0.5, 0.5 - margin left, margin top
    const margins = {top: 60, bottom: 30, left: 30, width: 595};
    const pdfDocument = doc.fromHTML(source, margins.left, margins.top, { width: margins.width, },
      // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
      function(dispose) {
        doc.save('news-summary.pdf'); // Generated PDF
      }, margins
    );
  }
```

After some research I found the jsPDF function `splitTextToSize()`. I used this to split the String into a String Array and join again with line breaking `<br>` tags.

This partially worked, but **badly formatted the PDF and took new lines when not needed** due to the restrictions of this method.

**TypeScript Code (using splitTextToSize()):**

```
const editor1ContentSplitArray = doc.splitTextToSize(editor1Content, 850);
const source = editor1ContentSplitArray.join('<br>');
```

**Using manually inserted line breaks**
[image]

**EDIT**
Some extra information on this:

I am copying the above text from another website, pasting it into a rich text editor (`CKEditor 5`), then I have a button which `onClick` function contains the TypeScript code above to carry out the conversion.

Comment: Hi, do you mind to also add exact html for `this.editorComponent1` and other html items you are trying to print?

Comment: Hi, maybe a silly question but I see that you area using `const margins = {top: 60, bottom: 30, left: 30, width: 595};` have you tried different `width`? Does the overflow still happens if you set width to `500`?

Comment: Looks like [fromHtml was deprecated](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1741#issuecomment-419226743).  [html2pdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/e973818a7e6b48d62a6ef7daca0d7e2290d016b4/src/deprecated/html2pdf.js#L22) is also deprecated, but it looks like it might have wrap options? Its strange because they have a file to [test line wrapping](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/b9f932cd2e22c82db0a39f0225521945a2568809/examples/basic.html#L247), but I'm not seeing anything about line / word wrapping in the [documentation](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join the string array.

Try inserting the string array into the `doc.fromHtml` or use `doc.text` as doc.text takes both string and string array as argument

Here what you need to do:

```
generatePdf() {

    console.log('Generating PDF');

    const doc = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'a4');

    const editor1Content = this.getEditorHtml(this.editorComponent1); // HTML string
    const editor2Content = this.getEditorHtml(this.editorComponent2); // HTML string

    const concatEditorContent = editor1Content + editor2Content; // combined HTML string


    const margins = {top: 60, bottom: 30, left: 30, width: 595};
    const source = doc.splitTextToSize(concatEditorContent, 850);

    const pdfDocument = doc.fromHTML(source, margins.left, margins.top, { width: margins.width })


    function(dispose) {
        doc.save('news-summary.pdf'); // Generated PDF
    }, margins);

}
```